# Proxying with django and gunicorn

Tags: python, django

I have a django application that i serve using gunicorn. I do that by using the method prescribed on the gunicorn site - embedding gunicorn into my django application.

I'm trying to set up a proxy into my application so that when you go to "http://mysite.com/proxy/" it does proxy you to "http://mysite.com:8100".

I know i can do that with apache and other webservers. For some reasons i would prefer to do it directly with gunicorn/django. One of theses reasons is keeping everything in the same place.

My question is, what is the best way to do that ? Also is it a terrible idea altogether ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deploy some proxy application into your gunicorn installation, such as [WSGIProxy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WSGIProxy).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. This is probably the right solution but i can't say i have tested it since i resolved myself to use apache + virtualhosts and mod_wsgi. It is much simpler for my use case in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I've written dj-revproxy for easy integration of a proxy in django. Bonus point it's using restkit which use the gunicorn HTTP engine. (I'm one of the gunicorn authors). More info here:

https://github.com/benoitc/dj-revproxy